# Outlook 2007 and 2010 placing white spaces between images

Tags: html, css

I have been searching for a fix for this for days and have inserted many different CSS and HTML tags that aren't fixing my issue. I have four separate images in their own tables (as I read that Outlook puts in breaks where it's decided a page should end) but there is an enormous pixel break being inserted between my third and fourth image. Any tips at all are welcome. I removed some of the code for privacy but this is the general format I've used for each of the four images. Thanks!

```
    <div>
<table style="width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="line-height: 1px; font-size: 0.0em;"><img alt="BlahBlahBlah" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35156/public/abc.jpg" border="0" height="1053" usemap="#Map" width="600" style="color: white; font-size: 12px; display: block;" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr style= "page-break-before: always">
<td align="center" valign="top" style="line-height: 1px; display: block; font-size: 0.0em;"><img alt="BlahBlahBlah" src="http://hosting-source.bm23.com/35156/public/abc2jpg" border="0" height="870" usemap="#Map2" width="600" style="color: white; font-size: 12px; display: block;" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: the style declaration for `<table>` is invlid, you have the double quote ending after the width instead of at the end, and each value needs a semi-colon after it. Basically your border-collapse, mso-table-lspace etc are getting ignored.

Comment: Nice catch! Changed that. Still seeing a huge gap between the two images, added some new styling. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to validate your HTML, for instance your heights do not specify units, the code is very messy. Normally you would separate out the styling using a css stylesheet or earlier <style> tag. I'm not sure why you are inserting a page break before the 4th image, and I don't see any margins being set. Inspect the DOM using a tool to see what is happening that causes the gap.